# python, rpm names sort by version

Tags: python

I've a trouble in sorting the rpms by version. If I use simple .sort() it is not sorting with the version.

> > > data = ["fininstapiserv-protected-stage-100.1-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-101.9-2.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-103.0-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-103.4-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-104.9-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-105.0-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-109.0-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-112.1-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-98.0-1.i686.rpm",
> > >       ... "fininstapiserv-protected-stage-99.0-1.i686.rpm"]
> > >
> > > data
> > >       ['fininstapiserv-protected-stage-100.1-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-101.9-2.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-103.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-103.4-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-104.9-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-105.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-109.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-112.1-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-98.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-99.0-1.i686.rpm']
> > >
> > > data.sort()
> > >
> > > data

['fininstapiserv-protected-stage-100.1-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-101.9-2.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-103.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-103.4-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-104.9-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-105.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-109.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-112.1-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-98.0-1.i686.rpm', 'fininstapiserv-protected-stage-99.0-1.i686.rpm']

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: float(x.split("-")[3]))
```

Check the Python [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) on sorting for more info.